# FileNotFoundException, Could not find Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll v5.0.2

Tags: c#, .net, azure, dll, azure-storage

I downgraded my dependency on Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage from 5.0.2 to 4.3 but my Console Application still attempts to load the   5.0.2 version of the library.
I am using NuGet, VS 2015. I have Microsoft Azure Libraries 2.7 installed ony my computer.
I was able to confirm that all my compiled dll have a dependency on Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll v 4.3 , there aren't any reference left to the 5.0.2 version in none of .csproj. The flag SpecificVersion has been set to True for all the references.

My question is: Is there some sort of cache that would need to be cleared?
The FileNotFound exception is raised the first time I access a symbol defined in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll (CloudStorageAccount)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the project within your VS solution and select clean - then rebuild. Otherwise you can use the assembly binding log viewer to try to better understand how it is that you have a dependence on 5.0.2. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Thank you, will check it out.